# laravel link a registration form to database field

Tags: laravel

I am using teams in laravel and want to add a company name field to my registration form instead of it running the standard:

```
'name' => explode(' ', $user->name, 2)[0]."'s Team",
```

I am still wanting to keep the field called name but use the input fields data, I have tried changing the method to:

```
protected function createTeam(User $user)
    {
        $user->ownedTeams()->save(Team::forceCreate([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'name' => $user['company_name'],
            'personal_team' => true,
        ]));
    }
```

but it doesn't work as intended. My register.blade.php is:

```
   <div>
   <x-jet-label value="{{ __('Company Name') }}" />
   <x-jet-input class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="company_name" :value="old('company_name')"  autofocus autocomplete="company_name" />
   </div>
```

my migration is unchanged as I am wanting to force the name through my form instead of it generating it based on the user input of name.

[image]

The complete CreateNewUser method is:

```
public function create(array $input)
    {
        Validator::make($input, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
        ])->validate();

        return DB::transaction(function () use ($input) {
            return tap(User::create([
                'name' => $input['name'],
                'email' => $input['email'],
                'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
            ]), function (User $user) {
                $this->createTeam($user);
            });
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create a personal team for the user.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return void
     */
    protected function createTeam(User $user)
    {
        $user->ownedTeams()->save(Team::forceCreate([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'name' => $user['company_name'],
            'personal_team' => true,
        ]));
    }
}
```

Comment: as I understand you just want to add new column with name company name right?

Comment: @NurbekBoymurodov What I mean is when you create a user in livewire teams by default the teams name is made with 'name' => explode(' ', $user->name, 2)[0]."'s Team", but I want to use the form and have people fill out their business name.

Comment: ok just you need send $input variable with $user it will be like this  function (User $user, $input) {  $this->createTeam($user);  });   and your function will  be protected function createTeam(User $user, $input) now you can use $input['company_name'];